# Split String in Array into an array autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Trying to read a CSV file in Auto Hot Key and line by line split the line by "," to pull out the last two columns of each line. Currently just trying to get the string to split into an array. I can print each line with the line 
`MsgBox, A_LoopReadLine` but cannot split the string inside of the variable.

Have tried StringSplit and StrSplit but I am sure the syntax is incorrect.

```
MyArray := Object()
Loop, read, %fileop%
{
    MyArray.Insert(A_LoopReadLine) ; Append this line to the array.
    index := 1
    MsgBox, %A_LoopReadLine%
    ;MyArray.
    ;MsgBox, % StrSplit(A_LoopReadLine ,",")
}

Loop % MyArray.Length()
    MsgBox % StrSplit(MyArray[A_Index],",")
```

Comment: Related: [How can I split tab-delimited strings in Autohotkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45620437/3357935)

Answer (score 2):

> Trying to read a CSV file in Auto Hot Key and line by line split the
>   line by "," to pull out the last two columns of each line.

```
MyArray := Object()
Loop, Read, %fileop%
    MyArray[A_Index]:=StrSplit(A_LoopReadLine,",")
```

This will store your csv file in `MyArray[row][column]` format. E.g to access second item in fifth row: `MyArray[5][2]`

```
for k,v in MyArray
    v.RemoveAt(1,v.Length()-2)
```

Above will remove all but last two items from each row.

---

Documentation:

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/For.htm

https://autohotkey.com/docs/objects/Object.htm#RemoveAt_v1121+

https://autohotkey.com/docs/objects/Object.htm#Length

---

Edit:
And to as to why your code did not work. It kinda did.
The thing is that `StrSplit()` returns **object**, **array** so with below line you were trying to display object in MsgBox, this is not allowed.

```
MsgBox % StrSplit(MyArray[A_Index],",")
```

This for example would work:

```
MsgBox % StrSplit(MyArray[A_Index],",")[1]
```