# How can I split tab-delimited strings in Autohotkey?

Tags: string, split, autohotkey, csv

I have a series of tab-delimited strings copied to the Windows Clipboard. I want to split these strings into arrays using the tab character.

```
Unit    Dept_ID Name
CORP    0368    Admin
CORP    3945    Programmer
SESHAN  4596    Software Engineer
```

I'm trying to use [StringSplit()](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringSplit.htm), but I can't figure out how to use 'tab' as my delimiter. I've tried a few different methods, but none seem to work.

```
clipboard = %clipboard%  ; Convert to plain text
StringSplit, MyArray, clipboard, `\t` ; Split string using tabs
MsgBox % "MyArray[1] = " . MyArray[1] ; BUG: Prints empty string
```

**How can I split a tab-delimited string in AutoHotkey?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to split them to an array of lines with:

```
lines := StrSplit(clipboard, "`n")
```

Then you can loop over all the lines and split them to columns creating a multidimensional array:

```
columns := []
for index, value in lines
    columns.Insert(StrSplit(value, "`t"))
; examples
MsgBox % columns[1][2] ; Dept_ID
MsgBox % columns[2][1] ; CORP
MsgBox % columns[2][2] ; 0368
```

Note that Autohotkey has 2 types of arrays the "new" type which are actually objects and you use them with `arr[index]` and the older pseudo arrays. In your code you mixed them up, StringSplit returns a pseudo array and can't be used with `[]`. I recommend you read about arrays in the [documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Arrays.htm).

Comment: Based on your answer, [I've created a reusable function which can split arbitrary-delimited strings.](https://pastebin.com/9RA5KpVH)

Answer (score 1):

**This splits tab delimited clipboard contents into an array**

```
MyArray := StrSplit( clipboard, "`t" )
MsgBox % "MyArray[1] = " . MyArray[1]
```

**Functionally equivalent**

```
StringSplit MyArray, clipboard, `t
MsgBox MyArray1 = %MyArray1%
```